# Is it possible to update/edit/modify chrome extension internals file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have my chrome extension directory tree [here](https://github.com/duckimann/idfilter/), can i use "background.js" to open, edit and save the extension internal files? For example edit file "saver.php" and save to exactly that path?

Open and edit the file is not a problem to me (i can use fetch / FileSystemDirectoryEntry api to get the file and edit) but idk anything about the "save" part i just mentioned above.